# android.app.Application cannot be cast to Activity

Tags: android, google-analytics

In my app project i have a `class` that extends `Application`. (in my case this is `AnalyticsApplication` in order to use [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/), but my problem is more general.)

I created `public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application`, also changed my application name property in the manifest to `android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"`.

Everything is going well, until i created another `class` called `MyUIHelper` that should perform many UI changes, on behalf of my `MainActivity`.
So from `MainActivity` i created the helper:

```
mUIHelper = new UIHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

The `MyUIHelper` constructor is:

```
public class MyUIHelper {

    private MainActivity context

    public MyUIHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = (MainActivity) context;
    }


    private void makeUIChanges(int id) {
        context.findViewById(id);
        // ...
    }
}
```

**The problem** is that i get the exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.MyApp.AnalyticsApplication cannot be cast to com.MyApp.MainActivity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you used

```
getApplicationContext()
```

And you casted it to activity in constructor

```
 public MyUIHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = (MainActivity) context;
}
```

Here the context is of application so it cannot be cast to MainActivity.

You should use the context of activity.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    void onCreate(...){
      //You can get context of activity here using 'this'
    }
}
```